# convert dictionary values to a list of values python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am quite new to Python and want to know how to convert the below key->value pair dictionary to key-> [value] i.e my value is a list so that I can append more elements to the list. 
My dictionary is as follows:

```
{'Mississippi': '28', 'Oklahoma': '40', 'Delaware': '10', 'Minnesota': '27', 'Illinois': '17', 'Arkansas': '05', 'New Mexico': '35', 'Indiana': '18', 'Maryland': '24'}
```

How can I convert to:

```
{'Mississippi': ['28'], 'Oklahoma': ['40'], 'Delaware': ['10'], 'Minnesota': ['27'], 'Illinois': ['17'], 'Arkansas': ['05'], 'New Mexico': ['35'], 'Indiana': ['18'], 'Maryland': ['24']}
```

So I tried to do this:

```
dict_cntrycodes= {k: [v] for k,[v] in cntry_codes}
```

But I am gettin ERROR: Too many values to unpack.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> testDict = {'Mississippi': '28', 'Oklahoma': '40', 'Delaware': '10', 'Minnesota': '27', 'Illinois': '17', 'Arkansas': '05', 'New Mexico': '35', 'Indiana': '18', 'Maryland': '24'}

>>> {k: [v] for k, v in testDict.items()}
{'Mississippi': ['28'], 'Oklahoma': ['40'], 'Delaware': ['10'], 'Minnesota': ['27'], 'Illinois': ['17'], 'Arkansas': ['05'], 'New Mexico': ['35'], 'Indiana': ['18'], 'Maryland': ['24']}
```

You are getting the too many values to unpack error since the keys in the first dictionary are strings and not lists. The following works.

```
>>> elem = "abc"
>>> [elem] = ['abc']
```

But, this gives an error.

```
>>> [elem] = "abc"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
    [elem] = "abc"
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

This is because you are trying to unpack three elements (`'a', 'b', 'c'`) to one element `elem`.

If you do this, the problem goes away

```
>>> [a, b, c] = "abc"
>>> print a, b, c
a b c
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to edit your original dictionary, then do this.

```
d = {'Mississippi': '28', 'Oklahoma': '40', 'Delaware': '10', 'Minnesota': '27', 'Illinois': '17', 'Arkansas': '05', 'New Mexico': '35', 'Indiana': '18', 'Maryland': '24'}
for i in d: d[i] = [d[i]]
```